# Meteor: why does `Promise.await` not need `Promise.async`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, promise

I was trying to make a method which would await multiple promises being fulfilled (easier to use promises for this application). I figured the `async/await` within the `Promise` package would do the job. I made the following function.

```
execute: Promise.async(function (routine) {
  let listener = Meteor.bindEnvironment(data => console.log(data));
  this.on('data', listener);

  Promise.await(Promise.all([
    this.sendCommand('startup'),
    this.sendCommand('begin process'),
    this.awaitMessage('ok')
  ]).finally(res => {
    this.removeListener('data', listener);
  }));
});
```

This does not work as it returns immediately. However, if I remove the `Promise.async` from the function, it seems to work perfectly fine just like a future-wrapped function.

Why is this? Generically, in node applications using es7 async/await, it looks like this:

```
let login = async function () {
  let user = await getUserRecord();
  return await login(user);
}
```

So, am I doing something wrong in meteor?